# Numerical Treatment of Dirac Delta in Finite Difference Scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I'm considering a particle in a spatial domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which secretes some chemical substance with production rate $q_0$, and is subject to a force proportional to the gradient of its own emitted chemical field, $\nabla c$. I'm assuming that the chemical diffuses in the environment with rate $D$ and decays with constant rate $\alpha$. The concentration of the chemical substance then evolves according to

$$
c_t = q_0 \rho(\mathbf{r},t) - \alpha c + D\nabla^2 c \tag{1}
$$

where $\rho(\mathbf{r},t) =  \delta(\mathbf{r} - {\mathbf{r}_a}(t))$ represents the chemical point source. Similarly, ${\mathbf{r}_a}$ is the trajectory of the particle, determined by

$$ m\ddot{{\mathbf{r}}}_a = \gamma\nabla c + \mathbf{R}(t), \tag{2}
$$

where $\gamma$ is a measure of the particle's response to the concentration gradient and $R$ is a force due to thermal noise. I would like to solve (1) and (2) numerically using a finite difference scheme. The problem, however, is in how to treat the Dirac Delta appearing in (1).

Let $C_{ij}^n \approx c(x_i,y_j,t_n)$ denote the numerical approximation to $c$ at the grid point $(x_i,y_j,t_n)$. Then, if I use an unconditionally-stable time-differencing procedure - let's say the Crank-Nicolson scheme - then one arrives at the following system of difference equations,

$$
\frac{C_{ij}^{n+1} - C_{ij}^{n}}{\delta t} = q_0\frac{1}{2}( \rho(\mathbf{r}_a^{n}) + \rho(\mathbf{r}_a^{n+1}) ) - \alpha\frac{1}{2}(C_{ij}^{n} + C_{ij}^{n+1}) + \frac{1}{2}D(\nabla_h^2C_{ij}^{n} + \nabla_h^2C_{ij}^{n+1} ) \tag{3}
$$

where $\nabla_h^2$ is the discretized Laplacian operator. The problem is computing $\rho(\mathbf{r}_a^{n+1})$, as this requires me to have knowledge of the particle's position at the next time step. Is there any way around this? Can I omit this term somehow and still maintain unconditional stability in time?

As a side note, if anyone knows of papers addressing the numerical treatment of Dirac Deltas in time-dependent problems, please provide links.

Comment: An alternative framework that may be better-suited would be a finite-volume scheme. It should give roughly the same discretization of all the terms except that the source term now only requires you to know what cell the particle is in, not its precise position.